# docker-compose single file volume sharing

Tags: php, sockets, nginx, docker, docker-compose

I want to connect a `nginx` and a `php-fpm` container using a unix socket and have the `php-fpm` be completely disconnected from any network for security reasons.

I could of course just create the `php-fpm.sock` file somewhere on my docker host and mount it into both containers, however I would like the socket file to be automatically cleaned when the containers shut down and not have to worry about creating / shipping it with my `docker-compse.yml`. I therefore thought about creating a named volume in `docker-compose` and mount it as `/var/run/`. This is however (I think) not good, because I don't want everything in `/var/run/` to be shared, but only `php-fpm.sock`. Is there a way to create a named single-file volume in docker-compose?

Answer (score 1):

If the directory structure is as:

```
.
|__docker-compose.yml
|__php-fpm.sock
```

Then you can use following volume in your compose file:

```
volumes:
  - ./php-fpm.sock:/var/run/php-fpm.sock
```

Comment: yes. this is the solution i settled with now. I just find it a bit "ugly" to manually provide a unix socket file.

Comment: While browsing through https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/, I found that, using `-H` option in Docker CLI, you can provide which Daemon socket(s) to connect to. But am not sure if that would be helpful to you in this case.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, instead of mounting `/var/run/` just mount `/var/run/php-fpm.sock`

Comment: I will try this in a sec, however I am convinced that this will just create a folder `php-fpm.sock` instead of a file

Comment: Tested: does not work. Mounts a folder of the same name.

Comment: It creates a new folder with that name if the requested file is not present!